# not cursor at all with err msg :Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to run simple update , not cursor at all :) in Microsoft SQL Server
and I'm getting a strange error message .

Here is the update statement:

```
update [MaintenancePortal].[dbo].maz_batia
set mok_sap_num = '00001009999' ,
         mok_sap_work_order = '00000123123',
         mok_sap_status = 'אאאאא',
         mok_sap_status_work_order = 'בבבבב',
        -- mok_equ_bz_description = NULL,
         mok_location_description = 'גגג>ב8>גגג',
         mok_work_order_cost_center = 'רררר',
         mok_work_order_date = '2020-03-11',
         mok_work_order_description = 'אבגאבגאבג'      ,
         mok_sap_tibco_status = 'SAP statuses updated',
         mok_user_open = 'מממממ'
         mok_department_desc = 'גגג>ב8>גגג'
 where mok_sap_num = '00001009999'
```

This is the full error msg:

> Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SendMail, Line 63 [Batch Start Line 76]
> Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

What can be the problem ? I'm going crazy :(

Thanks

Comment: Is there an UPDATE trigger on your maz_batia table?

Comment: yes !!!! i looked it up now ... so this is the problem ?

Comment: That would be my guess. There is an issue with the UPDATE trigger that needs addressing. Also, I would look into an alternative to using a CURSOR--especially in a trigger.

Comment: ok , i dont know how to thank you enough !!! this is the problem , i disabled the triger and finally the update is running.  now i can check the problem . thanks again !!! :)

Comment: You're most welcome.